# Stack Exchange Alexa Skill

Tags: app

An Amazon Alexa skill to browse hot questions across Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange Q&A network. With account linking enabled, you can even cast upvotes and downvotes and check your global inbox.

Available (for free) on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077XLY8XV).

Write access required for casting upvotes/downvotes.

**Source code**: https://github.com/MaxHorstmann/StackExchange-Alexa

**License**: MIT

Other comments / suggestions / pull requests welcome.